# ByDay in iCal is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, icalendar

"Daily", "Weekly" and "Monthly - same day of the month" is working correctly but when i use "Monthly- same week of month" (any week like first week/second week and any day like sunday/monday) then it is not opening correctly on outlook. iCal of that rule is opening same as "Monthly- same day of month" I wrote following code:-

```
  `RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20170630T000000;BYDAY=1FR`
```

what is the problem in above LOC?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your UNTIL date has no timezone.  You can either use UTC time or add a TZID parameter, as shown below:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20170630T000000Z;BYDAY=1FR
RRULE;TZID=America/New_York:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20170630T000000;BYDAY=1FR
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting here. I have to use local timing and the local time form is simply a time value that does not contain the UTC designator nor does it reference a time zone. For example, 11:00 PM.